# How can I go into a directory in filename completion?

Tags: autocompletion, command-line, filesystem

Consider a directory structure like this:

```
topdir/
  file1
  file2
  foo/
    bar1
    bar2
```

Say I want to open some file in `foo/` in a new tab.
I would first write `:tabe topdir/`, and then keep hitting `<TAB>` until `:tabe topdir/foo/` is displayed.

Then, I want to tab-complete the files in `foo/`.
But if I just hit `<TAB>` again, I'll wrap around to `file1` instead of going down into the `foo/` directory.

I can get around this by typing and deleting a space, but this seems kind of ugly.
Is there a way to directly say, "yes, this is the partial completion that I want—now tab-complete again as if I had entered this command manually up to this point"?

(For reference, my `wildmode` is `full`.)

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569348/vim-in-ex-command-mode-how-to-complete-the-path-only-up-to-the-first-non-unique).

What do you have `wildmode` set to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply press the right arrow key.

[image: demonstration]

Answer (score 8):

I prefer to type / because extra/////slashes///are//ignored.

Also, the arrow keys are poison. :)